# jquery append tag to div

Tags: jquery, jsp, tags

I would like to add dynamically a field to my form, here is what I'm doing now:

JQuery:

```
$('#addField').click(function(){
    $('#divTest').append("<html:text property='titles'/> <br> <br>");
});
```

JSP:

```
<html:form action="/test.do">
    <div id="divTest">
    </div>      
    <html:submit property="submit" value="Submit"/>
</html:form>
```

Add

It's not working, does anybody have an idea?

Comment: you cannot append a jsp tag.. Jquery wont recognize it.. !

Comment: Not only jQuery, the DOM itself will not consider it as a recognized element.

Comment: Add HTML tags not jsp tags.

Comment: I can add HTML tags, but won't be able to do the rest, I'm working with struts!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#addField').click(function(){
    $('#divTest').html("<html:text property='titles'/> <br> <br>");
});
```

Comment: No it doesn't work, as mentioned in the comments above, I think the DOM doesn't recognize the tag

Answer (score 0):

I finally opted for adding html tags!

```
$('#addField').click(function(){
    $('#divTest').append("<input name='titres' type='text'/> <br> <br>");
});
```